# Why is it that, the text on the right of the images is there instead of down?

Tags: html, css

```css
.samsung {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.iphone {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.xiaomi {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="phones">
  <h3>Best phones you can chose in 2023</h3>
  <div class="samsung">
    <img src="https://american-pc.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/61imYpK33qL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="no internet connetion" width="75%">
    <figcaption>s23 ultra</figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="Iphone">
    <img src="https://assets.shpresa.al/shop/2022/09/daac540d-cel1351-p.jpg" alt="no internet connetion" width="75%">
    <figcaption>Iphone 14 pro max</figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="xiaomi">
    <img src="https://www.giztop.com/media/catalog/product/cache/dc206057cdd42d7e34b9d36e347785ca/p/m/pms_1670747135.2084309.png" alt="no internet connetion" width="75%">
    <figcaption>xiaomi 13 pro</figcaption>
  </div>
  <br><br>
</section>
<section class="info">
  <label for="phoneA">Samsung</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="phoneA" name="footer" value="phone">
  <label for="phoneB">Iphone</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="phoneB" name="footer" value="phone">
  <label for="phoneC">xiaomi</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="phoneC" name="footer" value="phone">
  <br>
</section>
```

[the images that i have problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGOmB.png)
I am a bigenner at frontend web development and i was testing some new things i learned and i wanted to add 3 images and some options at the bottom but for some reasons it keeps on staying left.I copied some css online to make the images as they are there( i am still not faimiliar with css yet) can someone help me?

I tried sorrunding everything in section and div , adding br but nothing seems to work!

Comment: You forgot to create a [mcve]. Please read [ask] and [edit] to add one.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We can't debug code/markup we can't see. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question, and not as images, or links to 3rd-party sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You mistakenly called your class "Iphone" and "iphone"

I have fixed it below.

#### I think you need the `text-align:center;`

I have added it below. I have also added a `border: 1px solid red;`
If you remove the text-align:center, that border code will allow you to see more easily where it went wrong.

```css
.phones {
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
}

.samsung {
  
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align:center;
}

.iphone {

  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align:center;
}

.xiaomi {

  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h3>Best phones you can chose in 2023</h3>
  <div class="phones">
  <div class="samsung">
    <img src="https://american-pc.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/61imYpK33qL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="no internet connetion" width="75%">
    <figcaption>s23 ultra</figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="iphone">
    <img src="https://assets.shpresa.al/shop/2022/09/daac540d-cel1351-p.jpg" alt="no internet connetion" width="75%">
    <figcaption>Iphone 14 pro max</figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="xiaomi">
    <img src="https://www.giztop.com/media/catalog/product/cache/dc206057cdd42d7e34b9d36e347785ca/p/m/pms_1670747135.2084309.png" alt="no internet connetion" width="75%">
    <figcaption>xiaomi 13 pro</figcaption>
  </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
</section>
<section class="info">
  <label for="phoneA">Samsung</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="phoneA" name="footer" value="phone">
  <label for="phoneB">Iphone</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="phoneB" name="footer" value="phone">
  <label for="phoneC">xiaomi</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="phoneC" name="footer" value="phone">
  <br>
</section>
```

This gives you this, which I think is what you want? (The red borders are just so you can see that the text is centered, even if the images are not centered).

#### OK now at last I understand *which* text was mispositioned!

What you should do is avoid the "float:left;" approach. Instead, put the three phone image-and-caption DIVs into a single "flexbox", with the CSS I have added for the class `phone`.

Is this what you wanted?

[image]

Comment: the result is different now when i run it here, i am so lost

Comment: How about now? (Obviously remove the `border:1px solid red;` when you are happy with the layout.

Comment: except adding the red border nothing changed the text still right

Comment: Sorry, you originally said the text was too far LEFT. Has it now moved to the right for you? Remember adding the red border is not the fix. It is adding the text-align: center;

On my screen (screen-shotted above) the text is in the correct position. Please paste where the text is appearing on YOUR screen, and also indicate where you WANT it to be, since your wording is not clear to me.

Comment: i'am genuinely sorry i did not know how to phrase it since english isnt my native english , what i mean is you see those options to right " samsung iphone xiaomi"  i want them to be down like below the photos , the other options as well " the mini version the pro version etc" i want only the 3 images to be at the top( execluding the heading) and everything else to the bottom

Comment: Aaaaah! At last I see. OK this is easy. I will show you in a moment.

Comment: omg you fixed it thank you man , i reallty appricate your help as a beginner i had no idea what to do i guess i should learn css now

Comment: i cant upvote it said that i need 15 something to cast one but i did mark it as correct , im new here too i dont really know how things work around here yet but i am sure i am gonna be using this site a lot from now on

Answer (score -1):

Try this css for centering all text:

```
* {text-align: center;}
```

Try this css for centering all text within body

```
body {text-align: center;}
```

similarly, try this css for centering text within a specific class

```
.class_name {text-align: center;}
```

btw, share your code for people to better understand the problem.